# Switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Using switch statement create a code that output remainders( 0, 1, 2, 3 and others) when divided by 8. User inputs 20 integer from 0 till 99. Each remainder should show its total count.

Eg :This is how the output should be.

```
Total number with remainder 0 is 4. 
Total number with remainder 1 is 6.
Total number with remainder 2 is 5.
Total number with remainder 3 is 3.
Total number of other remainder is 2.
```

/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i, x[20];
cout << "Enter 20 integer numbers from 0 to 99: " <<endl;
for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
{
    cout << "Input " << i <<":";
    cin >> x[i]; // above this code, its working. 
}   
int remainder ; // From here im not sure how i should do it
switch (remainder)
{
case x[i] % 8 == 0 :
cout << "Total number with remainder zero is " << endl ; 
break;

case x[i] % 8 == 1 :
cout << "Total number with remainder one is " << endl ;     
break;  

case x[i] % 8 == 2 :
cout << "Total number with remainder two is " << endl ;     
break;  

case x[i] % 8 == 3 :
cout << "Total number with remainder three is " << endl ;   
break;  

default :       
cout << "Total of others is   " << endl ;  
}
return 0 ;
}
```

I have the general idea of the switch statements. I'm new to c++ and also to this website. Between the errors are at case part. It says i cant use x[i]. So should i just use x or other integer? Im not sure how to count the total number for each case. should i be using count++ ?

Comment: `switch(variable) { case somevalue; case othervalue`.  `case` should be values, not expressions. they're not an `if` statement.

Comment: so in my case it will be case o, case 1 and so on i assume...

Comment: Try `switch (x[i] % 8) { case 0: ... case 1: ... ... case 7: ...}`. You will also need a `for` loop around the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements are supposed to have a condition to test and then execute commands based on the results. The problem here is that you are testing a variable that does not have a value. The parentheses contain the data being tested. The cases are to execute given commands based on the resulting value. The thing you are testing here is `x[i] % 8`. This should go between in the parentheses. The case should just have the value attached to it.

```
switch (x[i] % 8) {
    case 0: //...
    case 1: //...
    case 2: //...
    case 3: //...
    default: //...
}
```

`case` will test whether the result of the action taken in the parentheses equal its assigned value (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, or default) and execute the assigned command.